# Link to a Gmail conversation that opens just the conversation?

Tags: gmail

I know I can [create a permalink to a Gmail conversation](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2007-11-17-n25.html), and I can [pop out a conversation in a new window](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/03/fast-new-windows.html).  What I'd like to do is combine the two.

With the [Getting Things Done®](http://www.davidco.com/about-gtd) software I am using, I like to add permalinks to the Gmail conversation(s) that are relevant to a particular action item or project.  For the most part this works great, but I don't like how it opens the full Gmail client - I'd much rather see just the conversation itself, like what can be seen when you click the "new window" button in Gmail.

Is there some way to create a Gmail permalink that does this?

Comment: you can try using m.gmail.com - the mobile version of GMail for this.

Comment: @Kevin - did you find a solution to this? When I look at how the popup comes out, I see that it seems to be javascript and grabbing the url from the popup doesn't generate anything. So, I'm guessing the answer is no... (besides MySelfPoddar's answer). Reposting his answer as an answer for future viewers

Comment: duplicate http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30297/how-to-link-or-share-an-email-in-gmail

Comment: @ivotron My question is related, but not duplicate.  In the linked question, the OP wants to share a GMail conversation with a friend, who is not logged in to the OP's account.  In my question, I am logged in to my account, so I don't have that restriction.  It makes a difference, as the top answer in the linked question makes clear.

Comment: Also see [this SO meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57836/proper-handling-for-different-question-same-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

m.gmail.com - the mobile version of GMail can be used to get a URL that points directly to your email and doesn't load the GMail application.

-Taken from myselfpoddar's comment above

Comment: Note: adding the answer so others can find it easier and so this question doesn't come up as "without an answer". @myselfpoddar please feel free to repost your answer as an answer so I an delete this :)

Comment: It's not ideal...the mobile and normal permalinks aren't closely related enough for me to "guess" the mobile permalink, so I have to actually go to the mobile website to discover it, which is a lot of work to create the link in the first place.  But it does seem to work.