# How to link or share an email in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, links, sharing

I often want to share an old email chain with a friend -- usually someone who was on on the chain in the first place.

Is there an easy way to send a "link" or otherwise share that email?

Comment: I am guessing from your question that forwarding the email thread is not an option, but I'm not sure why... Can you clarify why you wouldn't just forward the email?

Comment: @ShannonWagner The chains can be long. I don't wan't to forward a multi-email chain if I only want to cite one section -- and yet, I don't want to just copy/paste a section because the reader might want context.

Comment: It's 2020 and Gmail can't attach an email thread to an email (thread composition). Why some people have fears about The Singularity or Skynet or AI taking their jobs?

Comment: this would be a great feature to have especially for business emails (GSuite)

Comment: The best answer I have is still cloudHQ's service: "Gmail Email Links"
https://www.email-links.com/
PROS:
-Can open the link anywhere! (You don't need Gmail to open link.)
-Create link for multiple emails.
-Free.
-Not editable (nFiles -and another one I forgot- is editable by sender) therefore emails are trustworthy.
-Dashboard to track clicks.
//
CONS:
-Branded ("cloudHQ").
-Requires Chrome extension/addon.
(-Only works for Gmail)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no way to get a link or to share an email or thread with another person using just Gmail. Gmail gives you a [unique URL in the address bar for each message thread](http://www.labnol.org/internet/gmail-emails-have-permanent-web-address/6811/) but that URL is only accessible after you have logged in to your account, so another user would not be able to access the link.

Gmail Labs has a [Create a Document](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/12/new-in-labs-turn-email-into-google-doc.html) feature but the document it creates only seems to include the last email in a thread and there is no easy way to copy the remainder of the thread into that document for easy sharing.

One possible solution would be to print the thread as a PDF and send that.

Another possible solution would be to Forward All the thread to an Evernote account and use [Evernote's share by URL feature](https://support.evernote.com/link/portal/16051/16058/Article/629/An-Introduction-to-Sharing) to privately share the note.

There may be other 3rd party web-apps that can achieve this - worth a Google.

Comment: Solution from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/66067/3520 should be the way to go

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. It's inaccurate -- see the top-rated answer https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/66067/55579 .

Comment: But this solution using unique URL in the address bar is not working if the mail resides in **Snoozed** folder even after logged in to my account.

Comment: I find this solution in another post to be great actually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24463019/1526703

Answer (score 61):

I happened to need this feature to "reference" an old email with my colleagues. And I managed to do this with ["rfc822msgid:" search operator](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/35492).

Copy the Message-ID from the header of the message you want to reference, then search for it. For example, the Message-ID is `abcdefg@example.com` and you can search for `rfc822msgid:abcdefg@example.com` in the Gmail search box. Gmail will assemble a URL for you in the browser address bar, like this:

`https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/rfc822msgid%3Aabcdefg%40example.com`

You may want to remove `/u/0` part to make it a little more account-independent:

`https://mail.google.com/mail/#search/rfc822msgid%3Aabcdefg%40example.com`

Then you can send this link to your friends. When they click the link, they will perform a search for that Message-ID in Gmail. And since the Message-ID is unique, they can get one, and the very email you want to reference and the thread in which the message resides.

Oh, this message must be in your friends' Gmail inbox first, of course.

Comment: A userscript or bookmarklet to automatically generate that link would be useful; [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16827485/2014893) asks for ways to generate this `rfc822msgid` from GMail's own interface.

Comment: Great answer and +10pts for understanding the `/u/0` part!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: One way to automate the process in this answer is to create a Zapier Zap. I created one that, when I forward it an email, extracts the Message-ID, URL encodes it and puts a search link to that Message-ID in the body of a draft email, ready for me to copy and paste into calendar items etc. https://zapier.com/shared/928cf9294201f734479291376a9d93e119c7c7b6

Comment: These links don't work when I use them on Android, anyway to get them working there as well?

Answer (score 11):

You can use nFiles. Simply forward your email to `i@nfil.es`.

This will turn your email into a web page similar to this: https://nfil.es/w/hI6JK9/

Then you can share the URL of your email messages to your friends via email, IM or social media.

Details: https://nfil.es

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! 

Comment: Does it still work? I just tried it and I didn't get a link back.

Answer (score 8):

While this question already has an accepted answer, I just found an alternative that for me, more closely satisfies the OP's question:

While you can't share URLs as @OrangeBox points out, you can share search queries. Using [Gmail's Search Operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en), I've found that it's usually pretty easy to return a single result from even a large body of emails.

So the approach would be to:

1. Navigate to the email you want to link to, and copy something unique about it. For this example, let's just use a sentence from the email's body.
2. Paste that text, in quotes, into Gmail's search bar.
3. Copy the resulting url, which usually looks like :
   https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/%22some+words+from+your+email%22

...if this person has the email in their inbox, they should be brought to a search results page with a single result, where they can easily click on the email to open it.

There may be better ways of arriving at a unique email search query, but this one is easiest to execute, imo.

Cheers :)

Comment: Definitely the easiest - thanks for this

Answer (score -1):

if you click on print icon on top right of the email, it will open a page with print dialog, if you just disregard this panel and click cancel you can use the url for access the mail later on. For some reason there is another icon like open in a new window, but that one does not work if you copy/paste url to somewhere else, so for now I stick with print url.

Comment: Seems like the link only works for the person who created the link, not if a different user tries to access it - just like what's described in the first paragraph of OrangeBox's answer.

Comment: of course. it is a security concern, only authenticated person can see the link.

Comment: My point is that it doesn't work for sharing the e-mail with someone else, which is the OP's question.

Comment: I was looking for something for my own use, kinda like bookmarking an email, this worked. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

You can forward the email to multiple users, Sharing is not secure and that can your account accessed by others.