# How can I find a message by Message-ID in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, search

For archival purposes, I am storing a list of emails. I would like to be able to later find a particular message in my Gmail account. A unique message identifier is its `Message-ID`. However Gmail does not allow searching for it (returns an empty result). I don't really understand why, since the ID is in the message text.

Is there a way to retrieve a message by its `Message-ID` in Gmail?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This is now possible.

Announced in a recent [blog post](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/search-for-emails-by-size-and-more-in.html), you can now use a bunch of new search operators, including RFC 822 message ID.

From [Gmail Help - Using advanced search](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190)

> rfc822msgid:
>
> Find a message by the message-id header
>
> Example: `rfc822msgid:20050329231145.62086.mail@mail.emailprovider.com`
>
> Meaning: Locates the exact message with the specified SMTP message-id.

Comment: To make things easier, you can use this Chrome extension: [Gmail message ID finder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-message-id-finder/comcoiiifldaaejpbgbincdkoohihbae). It allows to copy the ID together with the search operator.

Comment: If you need to create a link with the message id, allowing user to go straight to the email, you can use: `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/{message_id}`

Answer (score -2):

I use multiple labels on a single conversation.

One label refers to the subject/project and the 2nd label is simply titled "keep". When I need to find one of these important conversations, I just search for "label:projectx label:keep". The result is the small set of conversations that meet both requirements.

Comment: If you don't want to care "where" your message lives aka the label shouldn't matter, you can use `#all` as part of the URL when you grab it in a specific message/thread. Like `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/abc123def456` per this excellent answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24463019/3794873