# Is it possible to search in gmail for specific message header content?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-search

I know Gmail has expanded the list of search options to allow a search for specific message IDs; however, I have not discovered a way to search for specific message header content. For example, I want to create a filter such that all emails in Spam with spf=fail in the headers are sent to trash. I know how to do this by creating an AppleScript job, but I rather set it up so that Google handles it on their end as messages are received. Anyone?

Comment: Did you mean Google Apps Script or Applescript?

Comment: *"I know Gmail has expanded the list of search options to allow a search for specific message IDs"*. That is a peculiar way to describe something that happened [12 years ago](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/35492/) .